# Bootable Windows backup in a pendrive?

Tags: windows

Windows often fails to boot (XP, Vista, 7 all) if the computer suddenly turns off due to power failure. Then I get stuck in boot loop of the boot screen. Is there any way to install Windows in a pendrive? Any software recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [Windows 8](http://betanews.com/2014/01/13/run-windows-8-or-8-1-directly-from-a-usb-drive-on-any-computer-for-free/):

> The Enterprise edition of Windows 8.x has a feature called **Windows To
>   Go** that lets you create a working version of Microsoft's tiled
>   operating system on a USB memory stick. You can boot into this and be
>   instantly up and running in the new OS from any computer. Which is
>   great -- provided you have the Enterprise edition of the OS and a
>   "certified" USB drive. If you only have the standard version of
>   Windows 8.x then the option isn't available to you.

Comment: Thank you. I guess nothing for windows 7 ultimate? And which USB drives are certified?